# 'Expected Identifier' error on typedef line:

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, enums, typedef

I have this piece of code:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
@class Completions;

typedef enum inputSource { KEY_TYPE = 0, WORD_SELECTION = 1, MOVEMENT = 3, BACKSPACE = 4 } InputSource;
...
```

For some reason I'm getting the error message on the line:

```
`typedef enum inputSource { KEY_TYPE = 0, WORD_SELECTION = 1, MOVEMENT = 3, BACKSPACE = 4 } InputSource`;
```

What is the problem here?

Comment: Without addressing your core problem, why not use , i.e., #define Key_Type 0 ?

Comment: Using #define is usually not the best solution as there is no type checking by the compiler.

Comment: Surprisingly, I don't have a problem with the above code even with `inputSource`. Could you give us more information about what the error message is?

Comment: @YuchenZhong, I provided an answer for the cause of the problem on my side, Thanks for assistance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cause of the problem was the fact that **iPhoneSimulator.platform** folder from the xcode Developer library was part of my project.

There is a parameter with the name **BACKSPACE** at this project and apparently there was some kind of conflict between the two parameters.

Answer (score 1):

Use: `typedef enum { KEY_TYPE = 0, WORD_SELECTION = 1, MOVEMENT = 3, BACKSPACE = 4 } InputSource;`

You do not need `inputSource`.

Or better, use the new  Objective-C style:

```
typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, InputSource) {
    KEY_TYPE = 0,
    WORD_SELECTION = 1,
    MOVEMENT = 3,
    BACKSPACE = 4
};
```